Excel Formula with a multiple condition

=IF(OR(L37="","",(IF(L37=6000,5800,6000))),ROUNDDOWN(L37/F37,0),1)
I need help to solve the formula above.
I used this formula to get the Number of Goods Quantity if the required length is 650mm for this particular item with a length of 6000mm.
The problem is where I have the standard 200mm waste for this item. The number of quantity I should get is 8 pcs instead of 9 pcs if using normal calculation.

6000 / 650 = 9.23. round that down is 9, seems your calculation is correct

yes 6000/650 = 9.23, but the problem is I want it to use 5800 instead of the std length of 6000 because 200 is a wastage material. so I use IF(OR as formula condition. If std size for column L is 6000 it will use 5800/columnF, other than 6000, it will use std size to divide.

This is how to update your formula:
=IF(L37="", "", ROUNDDOWN(IF(L37=6000, 5800, L37)/F37, 0))

Thank you. The formula worked, it solved my problem.
